JSON transformed to Hash when using credentials and fixtures
I am creating tests for my Ruby on Rails (7.2, Ruby 3.3.3) application.
The App uses Google Drive APIs. In order to avoid going through OAuth2 steps when testing, I want to put the Google Drive credentials inside fixtures.
Here is the model:
class Drive < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :provider, inclusion: { in: %w[google_drive, dropbox] }

  encrypts :credentials
end

The fixtures file looks like this:
# Read about fixtures at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

one:
  name: MyDrive
  provider: google_drive
  credentials: <%= Rails.application.credentials.google_drive_credentials %>

When I tried to add the JSON directly to fixtures, it worked. But I don't want to do this because it means the credentials will be committed to source control.
  credentials: "{\"client_id\":\"xxxxx\",\"access_token\":\"xxxxx\",\"refresh_token\":\"xxxxx\",\"scope\":[\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly\"],\"expiration_time_millis\":1722059441000}"

Here is the error I am encountering while running the test:
Error:
PullFilesMetadataJobTest#test_job_is_called:
MultiJson::ParseError: unexpected token at '{"client_id"=>"xxxxx", "access_token"=>"xxxxx", "refresh_token"=>"xxxxx", "scope"=>["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"], "expiration_time_millis"=>1722059441000}'


It looks like maybe you just forgot to convert the value to JSON, e.g. Rails.application.credentials.google_drive_credentials.to_json

Thank you so much @engineersmnky! It worked!
I am new to Ruby. Can you explain why do I need to add this? Especially I did put the same value that worked directly with fixtures inside my credentials file

Because a Hash is not JSON (as the error suggests) so {a: 1}.to_json #=> "{\"a\": 1}" but {a: 1}.to_s #=> "{:a => 1}"

It seems that my JSON string gets interpreted as Hash when used inside rails credentials too. And to_json helped

BTW you are using a string type column and not a JSON column, right?

Yes I am. I am using SQLite which doesn't support JSON columns.
I am planning to migrate to MySQL later but I have no intention to use JSON columns for this use case.
Why? Does it make a difference?
